# Sending Data to server of pageleave (RRWEB event)

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, screen-recording

I am trying to send rrweb event on pageleave. There are two options to send the data to server either using sendBeacon or fetch api calls. But sendBeacon doesn't work for more than 5sec on rrweb events and fetch is getting cancelled on pageleave, my current implementation goes like this

```
var params = new URLSearchParams({
  key : 'data',
  values : JSON.stringify(sessionPayload)
});
navigator.sendBeacon(`${this.apiHost}/session`, params);
```

How can i solve the problem of sending the data to server effectively.

```
document.addEventListener("visibilitychange", function() {
  if (document.visibilityState === 'hidden') {
    sendRecording(); //sends the recording to server
    sessionRecordingEvents = [] //empties the event array
  } else {
    startRecording(); //starts recording again
  }
});
```

Comment: add the full code snippet related to invoking sendBeacon, here the implementation is okay and there is no error on above snippets

Comment: The sendbeacon isn't working because of the size of the body to be sent. The RRWeb data for a particular number of events goes beyond 64kb which is the limit for sendbeacon, and i can't send only body limited to 64kb of data

Comment: I think you find out the answer